# Filter AngularJS without using ngOptions or ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, filter

Is there any way to filter a select-box without using ng-repeat or ngOptions in AngularJS via angular filters($filter).

I have a select-option code written like this:

```
<select>
   <option value="one">one</option>
   <option value="two">two</option>
   <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

and an input box which will be used to filter the content in the options:

```
<input ng-model="myFilter">
```

Comment: `<select ng-model="myFilter">` :)

Comment: Can I know why you shouldn't use ng-options/ng-repeat? Sadism? :)

Comment: i dont have my options in an array. n even if i put them in an array, dont have them in  a format required for using ngOptions or ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-if with a function.

```
<option ng-if="checkFilter('group1')" value="one">
```

and then in your controller

```
function checkFilter(value) {
  return myFilter.filter(function (element) { return element == value }); 
}
```